# When no 'Order by' is specified, what order does a query choose for your record set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I was always of the impression that a query with no specified 'Order by' rule, would order this by the results by what was specified within your where clause.

For instance, my where clause states:

```
WHERE RESULTS_I_AM_SEARCHING_FOR IN
ITEM 1
ITEM 2
ITEM 3
```

I would have imagined that the results returned for items 1, 2 and 3 would be in the order specified in the where, however this is not the case. Does anyone know what order it sorts them in when not specified?

Thanks and sorry for the really basic question!

Damon

Comment: Basically, if you don't care enough to specify an ORDER BY clause, you shouldn't care about what order is chosen. If you do care about the resulting order, then tell SQL Server by adding an ORDER BY clause that matches what you expect. Note that an ORDER BY clause *can* make a query more expensive by introducing potentially inefficient sort operations.

Comment: Keep in mind that without an _explicit_ order specification that the order may change after changing indexes on the table, updates to SQL Server, ... . It's a nice way to leave a time bomb for the next victim chosen to maintain the code.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If you don't specify an `ORDER BY`, then there is **NO ORDER** defined.

The results can be returned in an arbitrary order - and that might change over time, too.

There is no "natural order" or anything like that in a relational database (at least in all that I know of). The only way to get a reliable ordering is by **explicitly** specifying an `ORDER BY` clause.

**Update:** for those who still don't believe me - here's two excellent blog posts that illustrate this point (with code samples!) :

- Conor Cunningham (Architect on the Core SQL Server Engine team): [No Seatbelt - Expecting Order without ORDER BY](https://web.archive.org/web/20160808070425/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/)
- Alexander Kuznetsov: [Without ORDER BY, there is no default sort order](https://web.archive.org/web/20130922121836/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx) (post in the Web Archive)

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your answer to a some what trvial question!

Comment: @Muhammed Ali This was my first assumption but in this case there is a distinct lack of primary key's on the columns I have to use! Unfortunate but hey!

Comment: @MuhammedAli: it might **look like that** - but without `ORDER BY`, **there is NO order** guaranteed. Period. Get used to it.

Comment: Spot on. Love the article by Conor Cunningham.

Comment: The Alexander Kuznetsov link is no longer working

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: thanks - can't find any other place where Alexander might have published this - so unfortunately, looks like this one is gone forever ...... (too bad!)

Comment: There is a copy on archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20130922121836/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx

Answer (score 30):

With SQL Server, if no `ORDER BY` is specified, the results are returned in the **quickest way possible**.

Therefore without an `ORDER BY`, **make no assumptions about the order**.