# MySQL LIMIT returning incorect set of rows

Tags: mysql, cleardb

(Running on MS Azure cloud version of MySQL - CleadDB)

I have a simple query:

```
SELECT idx, date_added FROM my_table ORDER BY idx ASC LIMIT 100752, 10
```

I am expecting to get next 10 records after the idx 100752 (if present). However I get totally different records i.e.:

[image]

I verified the records are present so I ran the query again, this time with the records I know are there i.e.:

```
SELECT idx, date_added FROM my_table ORDER BY idx ASC LIMIT 102366, 10
```

yet I get the following unmatching rows again.

[image]

I know I am probably doing something silly. Help appreciated.

**EDIT/UPDATE:**
I followed some of the suggestions below and tested the results by using specific WHERE predicate rather then LIMIT function. Please see the results below. Both queries should return the same result - or so I would expect.

**TEST 1:**

```
SELECT idx, date_added  FROM attachments ORDER BY idx ASC LIMIT 67805, 20
```

returns:
[image]

**TEST 2:**

```
SELECT 
    idx, date_added 
FROM attachments 
WHERE
    idx >=67805 and idx <67825
ORDER BY idx ASC
```

returns:
[image]

I would expect both to be the same but this is not the case.

**SOLUTION:**
The LIMIT does not care about the primary auto-increment key. It cares about the number of rows (regardless of their index) so even if the idx is SORTed  - when some rows are missing (meaning there were some deletes in the past) it will offset the results based on the number of deleted rows. Thx All.

Comment: run: `SELECT max(idx), count(*) from attachments` and  see  results

Comment: @OTARIKI yes thx, and that returns nothing! WTH ?

Comment: @GurV are you serious ?

Comment: are you sure that "that returns nothing" ?

Comment: 100%, both columns are empty

Comment: do you have any row in table "attachments" ?

Comment: yes (my_table :) I do have all the records. Strangely even just a simple SELECT count(*) FROM my_table LIMIT 102366, 10 returns nothing... hmmm

Comment: `count(*)` returns only one row, no need limit in this case

Comment: when I do LIMIT 0, 10 I get the correct records but if I try LIMIT 59000, 10 the records id starting to be slightly off

Comment: it seems to return the right row idx up to about row 55000 after that it slips. I m more MSSQL guy so I do not know MySQL edge cases well enough. Could this be a normal behavior? BTW I am using the MS Azure MySQL version (ClearDB)

Comment: so, run `SELECT max(idx), count(*) from my_table ` and see results

Comment: yes, that returns over 200,000 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have gaps in your `idx` column.  That is, some values of `idx` were once used but no longer exist in the table.  As such the row number is not the same as `idx` (`LIMIT offset, row_count` works on row number not `idx`)

Why don't you try this query instead?

```
SELECT 
    idx, date_added 
FROM my_table 
WHERE
    idx >=100752 and idx <100762
ORDER BY idx ASC
```

Comment: Yes, thanks you for the alternate query solution. There is definitely more than one way how to get the result. However, I am interested in knowing wth is going on with the LIMIT feature. Please see my comments to OTARIKI, it may help to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First argument to `LIMIT` is offset. It is not related to any column in table.

If you have a table, where you inserted rows then deleted some rows randomly in between then `LIMIT 20, 10` will not give you rows with **id** 20 to 29. Rather it will give you 20th to 29th row after ordering your table (deleted rows don't play a role here)

Edit: If there is not `ORDER BY` then order can be arbitrary. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20050403/1435132

Comment: deleted rows are play a role - if you have deleted some rows and append new rows MySQL will reuse the free space. so if you select without order its possible that this new records are not at the end of the result

Comment: Yes, if there is no `ORDER BY` then order can be arbitrary. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20050403/1435132

Comment: ..sorry but I do not understand how this is answering my question. a) my query has ORDER BY and b) you can clearly see the rows being presents in the previous equerry so your theory does not hold here.

Comment: a) `ORDER BY` is good. b) You are expecting idx 102366 to show up when you do `LIMIT 102366, 10`. That is not how it works. (It works only idx is auto_increment, `order by idx` is used, and no row is deleted; I'm assuming some rows have been deleted in your case.)

Comment: The idx is AI and no rows had been deleted. Also, since I am sorting by idx I should always get consecutive rows as specified by the LIMIT ofset as long as the rows are present. Since I verified the rows are there this makes it mystery. Also the LIMIT starts slipping and returning wrong idx after the row 55000, anything before this returns exactly what is expected.  I am starting to thing this is ClearDB bug.

Comment: Can you share output of this? `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT idx) FROM my_table WHERE id < 102366`

Comment: I totally got it! You were right bro. I did not count the idx from over 100,000 and there were some deletes. This makes sense. The LIMIT (even though SORTet by idx) does not care about the idx itself, it cares about the number of rows! Hence the inconsistency when I reach the spot in the table where some of the rows had been deleted. Good work!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT idx, date_added FROM my_table ORDER BY idx ASC LIMIT 102366, 10

The offset is 102366 entries, not an idx offset starting at 102366. It starts at 104065 because there is (104065 - 102366) 1699 gaps in your my_table from 0 to 102366 is why its starting at 104065.

The same logic can be applied to your other queries.