# Select physically last record without ORDER BY

Tags: postgresql

An application inherited by me was oriented on so to say "natural record flow" in a PostgreSQL table and there was a Delphi code:

```
query.Open('SELECT * FROM TheTable');
query.Last();
```

The task is to get all the fields of last table record. I decided to rewrite this query in a more effective way, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TheTable ORDER BY ReportDate DESC LIMIT 1
```

but it broke all the workflow. Some of ReportDate records turned out to be NULL. The application was really oriented on a "natural" records order in a table.

How to do a physically last record selection effectively without ORDER BY?

Comment: Why not add `WHERE ReportDate IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: Have you seen this QA? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050341/when-no-order-by-is-specified-what-order-does-a-query-choose-for-your-record - when there is no `ORDER BY` then the order of returned results is **undefined** - there is no "natural order" - it could change based on the current phase of the moon or if you ever do a table garbage-collection if your DBMS reorders rows to be efficient.

Comment: @Dai: Thank you, I didnt see that QA. The key phrase there is **"might change over time"**. So, I will try to stay with ORDER BY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do a physically last record selection, you should use `ctid` - the tuple id, to get the last one - just select max(ctid). smth like:

```
t=# select ctid,* from t order by ctid desc limit 1;
  ctid  |               t               
--------+-------------------------------
 (5,50) | 2017-06-13 11:41:04.894666+00
(1 row)
```

and to do it without `order by`:

```
t=# select t from t where ctid = (select max(ctid) from t);
               t               
-------------------------------
 2017-06-13 11:41:04.894666+00
(1 row)
```

Its worth knowing that you can find ctid only after sequential scan. so checking the latest physically row will be costy on large data sets