# Based on this db query inside this method, i need to return the last record. Sometimes this query will return multiple records

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jsp

//This query can return multiple records, in that case of multiple records, always return last record from query.

```
public People(int peopleId) {

        Prepared Statement SQL= null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Getting Phone for " + personSerId);
            Prepared SQL= new DatabaseController(verbose);

            PreparedStatement secureStatement = prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
            s
            dbConnection.querySecureRecord(SQL);
               (((File) ("item")));
                theNumber.setPhone((String) dbConnection.getField("phone"));
                theNumber.phone(dbConnection.getField("number") == null ? "" : (((String) 
            }
        } catch (Exception masterException) {
            System.err.println("Database Query Error in : " + masterException);

        return the person;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any order guaranteed from the query?

Comment: Just sort your rows in way you need. Add in the end of query: "order by id desc".

Comment: Thanks Olek I think this may work. Compass the order is based on last inserted will appear last in sort.

Comment: What if I wanted to return just the latest, a single record, and not a group ordered by desc? Thank for all you guys help.

Comment: Guys order by wont work..I need to get last record in query result,. So a forloop might be useful and return last iteration. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do 3 things.

1. Specify an ordering by ( id, created date...): [this post says there is no guaranteed ordering if none is specified.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20050403/282956)
2. order descending so the first thing in the list is what you want
3. limit query to 1

it seems like one issue is that the database controller is meant to iterate over the result set even if only one result is expected. so you may still have to get the "first" result from the list even though there is only one (or possibly none) to get.

Comment: Thanks for youre response. This is a unique situation where if user updates a column the id will stay the same so ordering by id wont work. Based on query result the last result is always what i want in this unique situation. Im new to db how can i change the code to return last result by using a loop. Just return -1?

Comment: that is not unique. id's should always stay the same that's what ID means it is what IDentifies the object. if you see my reference you will see that if no ordering is specified you cannot count on a particular ordering. so if you need to add a col to that table that you can sort by. OR. maybe you can add a method to the db controller that jumps it to the last result set and call that instead of the while loop.

Comment: "maybe you can add a method to the db controller that jumps it to the last result set and call that instead of the while loop"  I will use this thanks

Comment: or if it already has a method like `getLast()` instead of `.nextRecord()`

Comment: from the code I present where in that method would i add the getLast()?

Comment: instead of `while (dbConnection.nextRecord()) {...do stuff ...break } it would be. `dbConnection.getLast(); doThing1();doThing2();` but in case there was 0 results you need to check or else get null pointer exception.