# PostgreSQL function used in QueryDSL is not working, returns ERROR: syntax error at or near "."

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jpql, querydsl

This is my very first question on stackoverflow, so sorry in advance if anything is not as precise as it should be

In my project, I use Hibernate (as ORM framework) with QueryDSL lib, PostgreSQL as a database.

Basically, I need to check the size of a list 'arr', which is a property of some 'X' class, so I googled and found a way to use postgres functions with querydsl as follows (before you ask, I **can't use native queries** by the requirements):

```
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();

builder.and(Expressions.booleanTemplate("function('array_length', {0})", qX.arr)
                .castToNum(Integer.class).gt(0));
```

Everything compiles fine, but when the repository method is being called, I get an error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "." Position: ...

I checked everything, but there are no "." in that position and near positions as well.
However, after setting `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` I found out that there is indeed a "." symbol somewhere in that position, and the result SQL statement looks like this:

`... and cast(array_length(`**.**`) as int4)>?`

which means, that JPA can't put my 'arr' inside the `array_length()` function (is that so?)

Why does this happen? Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you in advance

My entity class looks like that:

```
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
    @Entity
    @Table
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @TypeDefs({
            @TypeDef(name = "list-array", typeClass = ListArrayType.class)
    })
    public class X extends BaseClass {
    
        // private fields
    
        @Type(type = "list-array")
        @Column(name = "arr", columnDefinition = "bigint[]")
        @ElementCollection
        @OrderColumn
        private List<Long> arr;
    }
```

I tried without @ElementCollection and @OrderColumn annotations but that gives me cast errors

Comment: can you add your entity class showing how the array type is specified?

Comment: @fladdimir yes, sure. I have updated my question

Comment: seems like 2 problems here, I hope the answer helps?

Comment: Not sure which ListArrayType implementation you're using, but I've implemented Querydsl bindings for Hibernate-Types, which also has `array_length` support: https://github.com/jwgmeligmeyling/hibernate-types-querydsl-apt

Comment: @Jan-WillemGmeligMeyling it's com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.ListArrayType that I used, but I'll take a look at your suggestion, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@ElementCollection` and `@OrderColumn` are causing a first problem here. After they are removed (and the schema is setup correctly), the function call (SQL template) needs to be corrected.

---

The problem with `@ElementCollection` and `@OrderColumn` is that they represent an alternative approach for storing lists/arrays as part of an entity.
`@ElementCollection` stores the elements in a separate table, with each element in a separate row (each referencing the entity). To "remember" the correct order, an `@OrderColumn` is needed as part of the separate table, since rows are returned in arbitrary order if no order is specified (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20050403).

In contrast, `ListArrayType` and `@Column(columnDefinition = "bigint[]")` will enable saving the sequence of elements in *one column of an entity row*. Therefore, no separate table is used, and since the elements are not saved in separate rows, no additional order information is needed.

So **without** `@ElementCollection` and `@OrderColumn` the list mapping is already correctly setup. Be aware that your schema might currently be in a bad state, and you need to make sure that there is a `bigint[]` column in the entity table (can e.g. be auto-created by hibernate when `@ElementCollection` and `@OrderColumn` are removed).

---

**2.** Fixing the PostgresQL function call: `array_length` needs a second argument indicating the dimension of the array along which the length is returned (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html). So specifying the template string as follows should get you the correct result:
`"function('array_length', {0}, 1)"`
("1" being the requested array dimension).

Comment: Thank you, @fladdimir! It indeed was my wrong usage of a template - i registered ```array_length``` function in my Postgres dialect as ```registerFunction("array_length", new StandardSQLFunction("array_length", StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER));``` thinking that it will automatically place that '1' as an array dimension, but oh well. After I manually set the dimension, everything started to work! It's not retrieving any data tho, but that's another question's concern :)

Comment: As for those annotations, turns out, I dedn't really needed them. After I removed them, nothing bad happened. My column already had necessary type, and the schema is in the right state