# Linq FirstOrDefault ordering when OrderBy or OrderByDescending are not supplied?

Tags: linq, .net-core

If we have an EF entity with basic structure of

```
public class Entity
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string name {get; set;}
   public DateTime lastUpdated {get; set;}
}
```

And a collection of them with 4 entities:

```
entities = new List<Entity>{
   new { Id = 0, Name = "Thing One", LastUpdated = new DateTime(2020, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0,)},
   new { Id = 1, Name = "Thing One", LastUpdated = new DateTime(2020, 10, 4, 0, 0, 0,)},
   new { Id = 2, Name = "Thing One", LastUpdated = new DateTime(2020, 10, 3, 0, 0, 0,)},
   new { Id = 3, Name = "Thing One", LastUpdated = new DateTime(2020, 10, 2, 0, 0, 0,)}
};
```

If we use Linq to select the `FirstOrDefault` by the Name property.

```
   var selectedEntity = entities.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == "Thing One");
```

What is this going to return?

This is causing issues in a piece of code that I'm reviewing; which will be fixed by only allowing unique entities and using `SingleOrDefault`, but I'm curious at to what the `FirstOrDefault` is going to return by default when there is no `OrderBy` clause.

Comment: it's just undefined. in programming there's many such cases. in my opinion useless to study the behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first item matching this condition is returned, if there are multiple items matching the result is unpredictable/undefined. If you want to ensure a specifc item you need to apply an `OrderBy`:

```
var selectedEntity = entities
   .Where(e => e.Name == "Thing One")
   .OrderByDescending(e => e.LastUpdated)
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

What is returned by the database depends on the vendor. This related qustion might help: [When no 'Order by' is specified, what order does a query choose for your record set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050341/when-no-order-by-is-specified-what-order-does-a-query-choose-for-your-record)

Comment: cheers! the articles in the linked answer are very interesting. Relying on a FirstOrDefault with no ordering is certainly going to turn up in bug somewhere :-)

Comment: @RossHalliday: You're welcome. Yes, especially the first article is worth reading: https://web.archive.org/web/20160808070425/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/