# SQL - Case when lineid='01' then newid else id

Tags: mysql, sql, case, newid

I have this kind of data in my table

| lineid | price € |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 100.00 |
| 02 | 200.00 |
| 01 | 10.34 |
| 01 | 311.12 |
| 01 | 14.33 |
| 02 | 36.44 |
| 03 | 89.70 |
| 04 | 11.33 |

and i would like my output to be like this

| docid | lineid | price € |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 | 100 |
| 1 | 02 | 200.00 |
| 2 | 01 | 10.34 |
| 3 | 01 | 311.12 |
| 4 | 01 | 14.33 |
| 4 | 02 | 36.44 |
| 4 | 03 | 89.70 |
| 4 | 04 | 11.33 |

Its data for invoices and for every line that has lineid='01' it means that the info is for different invoice so i have to mark it with new documentID that i want you to help me create it with a command.

Its probably something easy but i am searching like a maniac here and i cant find the solution.

EDIT: Yes , it Is "increment docid each time lineid equals 01" what i want

Comment: You could use CASE and LAG here

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are asking about. Is it "increment docid each time lineid equals 01"? In that case, you must [define the order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20050403/11683) of your lines first. And [tag your database](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You could use running counts using something like below (assuming this is MS SQL you are talking about)

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [LineId] order by [LineId]) as DocId,
      [LineId],
      [Price]
  FROM [StackOverflow].[dbo].[RunningCount] order by [LineId]
```